Nautilus gapplication service use to much RAM
Using "htop" I see that nautilus gapplication service is using 12% of 47GB RAM and 60% CPU for several minutes, while I am not opening any software or opening files. Is this normal, what can cause this high usage? I use Ubuntu 22.04
Thank you

There's no way to tell unless you profile the application (requires sysprof and debug symbols) or you write clear instructions that reproduces the issue.
